# How to create a custom exclude validation rule in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I would like to create a custom rule that excludes an attribute under some condition, the only ways I could think about are:

1. manually verify the condition in the FormRequest and add the 'exclude' rule if my condition is ture (which is, imo, not so elegant)
2. (I'm not sure if this will work/ won't have side effects) create a custom validation rule that will remove the attribute from the request (request->remove($attribute)) if the condition is true.
   Is there any better way to do this ?

I couldn't find the implementation of any of the exclude rules either.

Comment: This is a bit vague to to point where i'm thinking it doesn't sound like a job for validation but rather a simple if check.

Comment: yeah but wondering if I can create a custom rule for that... something like new ExcludeWhenMySoComplicatedConditionIstrue

Comment: You can create custom validation rules by following the docs found here [Laravel | Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules). But seeing as how you have not defined any parameters for your question I am not sure how to answer it. I believe you should also look into [Laravel | Available Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules) to look for the conditional logic you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vague answer to match your vague question, but it is easily done with [conditional complex validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation). Use [the `withValidator()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests) to access the validator instance before the rules are applied.

```php
// assuming we're inside a FormRequest
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes(
        'some_field',
        'required|string|max64',
        fn ($data) => $data->some_other_field !== 1234
    );
}
```

First argument to `sometimes()` is the field you want to conditionally validate; the second is the rules you want to apply; and the third is a callback. The callback is passed the request data; if it returns true, the rules will be applied.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you ! I have 2 questions though:   
1- do I have to use it inside withValidator instead of just using $this->validator inside rules() method ?  
2- how is the 'exclude' rule implemented ? is it something like $this->request->remove('attribute') ?

Comment: I haven't tried accessing a validator instance within the `rules()` method, but there is a protected method `FormRequest::getValidatorInstance()` that's probably safer than just trying to access the property. The `exclude` rule doesn't remove the item from the request, just from the `FormRequest::validated()` return.

Comment: Ah thank you! any idea how to remove an attribute from validated data manually ?

Comment: `FormRequest::validated()` returns a simple array; it's easy enough to remove an element with `unset()`.

Comment: ah ok thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to exclude a validation rule based on conditions.

You can use `exclude_if`, `exclude_unless` and `exclude_without`.

Suppose you want to exclude a field validation if its another field's value is null, then you can use

```
['field1' => 'exclude_if:field2,null|<validation rules for field1>']
```

Again suppose you want to exclude a field validation unless the other value is not equal to 3, then use,

```
['field1' => 'exclude_unless:field2,==,3|<validation rules for field1>']
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I was looking for something for more complex conditions and @miken32 answer answers it well.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that since Laravel 8.55 there is the method 'when' in the Rule object that you can use inside your rules() method as follow to exclude an attribute:

```
Rule::when(MyCallBackThatReturnsABoolean, [/*RulesIfCallBackReturnsTrue*/], [/*RulesIfCallBackReturnsFalse*/])
```

For some reason, I can't find the method in the documentation.
for example to exclude an attribute if the condition foo==bar is false I could do:

```
Rule::when(function() use(foo,bar) { return foo===bar }, ['required', 'string'], ['exclude'])
```

Pull requests [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38361) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38450)
[Example of usage here](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-8-55-0)